# Django ModelForm not saving data

Tags: python, django

I've tried solutions from the following posts:

[Saving data from ModelForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046488/saving-data-from-modelform) : Didn't work

[ModelForm data not saving django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164680/modelform-data-not-saving-django) : Didn't work.

I'm trying to save data from a ModelForm into the model.

models.py:

```
class Testimonials(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    credentials = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    test = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    NO = 'NO'
    YES = 'YES'
    APPROVAL = ((NO, 'no'), (YES, 'yes'))
    verified = models.CharField(choices=APPROVAL, default=NO, max_length=3) #Field for making sure only verified testimonials are displayed

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
```

forms.py:

```
class TestimonialForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter your name'}), required=True)
    credentials = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter your designation'}), required=True)
    test = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control test-form-area', 'placeholder': 'Testimonial', 'rows': '5'}), required=True)
    verified = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta:
        model = Testimonials
```

views.py

```
def add_testimonial(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestimonialForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/testimonials/thanks/')
        else:
            print form.errors

    else:
        form = TestimonialForm()

    return render_to_response('templates/add_testimonial.html', {'form': form}, context)
```

Template:

```
<form id="testimonial_form" method="POST" action="/testimonials/thanks/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {{ field.help_text}}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add testimonial" class="btn btn-info test-button"/>
</form>
```

EDIT:

urls.py

```
url(r'^testimonials/all/', views.testimonials, name='testimonial'),
url(r'^testimonials/thanks/', views.testimonials_thanks, name='testimonial_thanks'),
url(r'^add_testimonial', views.add_testimonial, name='add_testimonial'),
```

However, on redirect, it doesn't save the form into the model which I'm checking from both PHPMyAdmin (using a MySQLdb) and the Django Admin panel. Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are POSTing to `/testimonials/thanks/` which should be changed to your `add_testimonial` route to have your view handle the POST. So, the solution is to change the `action` value in your template's form tag.

If you can post the relevant code from your urls.py I can provide a more specific answer as to what the value of the action attribute should be.

**Update**

The redirect will happen in your view when a valid form is POSTed. Change your template's action attribute value to:

```
<form id="testimonial_form" method="POST" action="{% url 'add_testimonial' %}">
```

In your view:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('testimonial_thanks'))
```

And make sure you include the following import in your view:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```

**Update 2**

Display your form errors in your template:

```
<form id="testimonial_form" method="POST" action="{% url 'add_testimonial' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="form-group text-error">
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {{ field.help_text}}
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.errors %}
            <span>{{ field.errors|striptags }}</span>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add testimonial" class="btn btn-info test-button"/>
</form>
```

**Update 3**

Now that you can see your form errors, you will need to provide your default value to the hidden field, and there's no need to make it a ChoiceField if the user has no choice (it's hidden!). So change the `verified` form field to:

```
verified = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial='no')
```

Also, it would be a good idea to verify the value in your view since even though the field is hidden, an enterprising, evil user can still POST other values.

Comment: Added urls.py. Also, my original code did have action as 'add_listing'. That saved to the model, but I wanted to redirect to another url on success so I changed action to `testimonials/thanks`

Comment: Great, I've updated my answer. Let me know how you get along.

Comment: And any changes to be made in the views.py? Because I tried this and there was no effect. It didn't redirect to `testimonials/thanks/`. If it helps, my form data in the console is as follows: `verified:`
`name:Save`
`credentials:Save`
`test:Save`
`submit:Add testimonial`

Comment: Ok, you may need to use your "thanks" url name in the view. see update

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. You can try it out [here](http://silverinnings.herokuapp.com/add_testimonial)

Comment: It may be that you have form errors, try displaying both the field errors and non-field errors on your template.

Comment: Yep, there's an error in the hidden input field.I've assigned it a default value of 'No', but it doesn't send it across to the model as the default shows empty.

Comment: That's your issue, set an initial value for the field. Also, there's no need to have verified be a choice field if the user has no choice since it's hidden. I've updated the answer again, this should do the trick!

Comment: hello, im new to django, and was wondering if you can explain what this part means action="{% url 'add_testimonial' %}" , im basically trying to use one template for my "posts/new" url and "posts/<id>/update" url. not sure if that's the best way to go but was just following a tutorial